# How to get data from Tab in Tabpane JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want get data from Tab in Tabpane JavaFX

I have 2 Tab in Tabpane, And each Tab I have a TextArea, I want click Button will get data from 2 tab

[image]

[image]

Here's my code:

```
btnThem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            i++;
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                    getClass().getResource("/fxml/tab.fxml"));
            Parent parent = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Tab tab = new Tab("Điểm " + i);
            tab.setContent(parent);
            tab.setClosable(true);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
            controllerTab = (ControllerTab) fxmlLoader.getController();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your code attempt.

Comment: Sorry but we need much more of your code: what is in the `tab.fxml`? What is the current code of `Parent`? How exactly there appears to be two tabs? This code seems to add only one tab.

Comment: Do you want a data of children nodes (textarea) in each anchorpane of tab ?

Comment: You need to get data from each TextArea !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous but it seems you want to get data from each `textArea` in `tab`.To do this you should get `nodes` `(children)` from each `tab` and by using `lookup()` we confirm and we parse `node` to `textArea`.I tried to figure your `scene` and made this example to help you :

```
public class example extends Application {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        TextArea textArea1 = new TextArea();
        Button button = new Button("button");

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            Tab tab1 = new Tab("tab1");
            Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2");
            tab1.setContent(textArea);
            tab2.setContent(textArea1);
            TabPane pane = new TabPane();
            pane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
            Node node1 = tab1.getContent();
            Node node2 = tab2.getContent();

            button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                if (node1.lookup("TextArea") != null && node2.lookup("TextArea") != null) {
                    TextArea area1 = (TextArea) node1.lookup("TextArea");
                    TextArea area2 = (TextArea) node2.lookup("TextArea");

                    System.out.println(area1.getText() + "   " + area2.getText());

                }
            });

            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
            root.getChildren().add(pane);
            root.getChildren().add(button);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

And you can see the result :

[image: Data in tab1]

[image: Data in tab2]

[image]

```
Hello ,tab1   Hello ,tab2
Deleting directory C:\Users\Electron\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Buttono\dist\run341573612
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```