# Getting TextArea from TabPane in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I have been using TabPane for containing a TextArea in each tab. Something like this:

```
Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
tab1.setContent(new TextArea());

Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
tab2.setContent(new TextArea());

TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);
```

Now I have to find the text area directly contained in the selected tab. How can I get it?

Comment: Find the `TextArea`. not the `Node`??? `TextArea` ***is a*** `Node`, so what do you mean??? Also when do you need to get it? The selection may change.

Comment: Maybe is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897569/how-to-get-data-from-tab-in-tabpane-javafx/47933052#47933052

Answer (score 0):

You can getContent from Tab:

```
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;

    Tab tab1 = tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    tab1.setContent(new TextArea());

    TextArea ta = (TextArea) tab1.getContent();
    ta.setText("123");
    System.out.println( ta.getText());
```

, but it's **Ad hoc** decision.